# Azure Policy to reject ReadOnly locks on specific resources

Tags: azure, azure-policy

This week we had an issue where an accidental ReadOnly lock on a Servic Bus prevented apps from authorizing (specifically Event Grid). To prevent this from happening again, we want to create a Policy to deny this for Service Bus resources. However, I can't get it to work.

At the moment, I have this:

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
      "equals": "ReadOnly"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

I'm assigning this to the Service Bus Namespace resources, but when I do it doesn't find any compatible resources. I think that's because it can't find a Service Bus Namespace that has a lock-level, as a lock is a separate resource type.

How can I create a Policy that does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Policy to reject ReadOnly locks on specific resources.

Here is the updated policy that denies the creation of `ReadOnly locks` on `Service Bus` resources.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces"
                },
                {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
              "equals": "ReadOnly"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

This policy will deny any requests to create or update a `ReadOnly lock` on a `Service Bus Namespace` resource.

Once assign the policy, any attempt to create or update a `ReadOnly lock` on the `Service Bus Namespace` will be denied.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't quite work as I want though. If I assign it to the ServiceBus.Namespace resource specifically, then it doesn't work (I can still make read-only locks). And if I don't assign it to a specific resource but just to a subscription, then I can't create read-only locks at all. I think it's because your policies if-statement is also true for locks on non-servicebus resources.